# Getting call to non-object error while writing a row in Zend Gdata

Tags: php, spreadsheet, gdata

I'm trying a very simple process of adding a row to a GoogleDocs spreadsheet using Zend GData.

Just to make sure I can access the spreadsheet okay, I'm having it pull the data from the spreadsheet and print it out, then see if it can write a row.

As you can see, it reads just fine, but I get a fatal error when it tries to write.

> array (   0 =>    array (
>       'firstname' => 'Stan',
>       'lastname' => 'Parker',
>       'dateofscreening' => '1.1.1111',
>       'peopleexpected' => '12',
>       'amountcharged' => '12.15',
>       'dvdsent' => 'No',   ),   1 =>    array (
>       'firstname' => 'Joe',
>       'lastname' => 'Smith',
>       'dateofscreening' => '2.2.222',
>       'peopleexpected' => '10',
>       'amountcharged' => '10.15',
>       'dvdsent' => 'Yes',   ), )
>
> **Fatal error:  Call to a member function insertRow() on a non-object in
>   /home/stparker/public_html/happy/gdata.php on line 56**

Here's the code:

```
 $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
 $query->setSpreadsheetKey($key);
 $feed = $spreadSheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);
 $entries = $feed->entries[0]->getContentsAsRows();
 echo "<hr><h3>Example 1: Get cell data</h3>";
 echo var_export($entries, true);



 $rowData = array 
 (
'firstname' => 'Big',
'lastname' => 'Smiley',
'dateofscreening' => '1.1.1111',
'peopleexpected' => '12',
'amountcharged' => '12.15',
'dvdsent' => 'No',
 );

  $spreadsheetService->insertRow($rowData,$key,'Sheet1');
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$spreadsheetService->insertRow($rowData,$key,'Sheet1');
```

To:

```
$spreadSheetService->insertRow($rowData,$key,'Sheet1');
```

Your capitalization wasn't consistent throughout the code, e.g., `S` in `Sheet`.